# I am using AsyncTaskExecutor to execute a callable method. But after few calls, it does not call the code in callable method

Tags: java, asynchronous, threadpool, callable

I am using  AsyncTaskExecutor(org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor)  to execute a callable method which in turns download pdf using async call. But after few downloads , it does not execute the code inside the callable method. It uses threadpoolexecutore to determine the size of threadpool.It seems the first group of threads are now getting stuck and not being released – which makes all the other following threads wait forever.

Can anyone tell  me if it is happening due to threads are reaching the max thread poolsize as this is affecting the prod environment?

```
    private static AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;
   public static <T> Future<T> executeTaskThread(final Callable<T>callable)
{
        return taskExecutor.submit(() -> {
          try {
           return callable.call();
          } catch (Throwable exception) {
           segment.addException(exception);
           throw exception;
          }  
        });
    }
```

Comment: please share code reference

Comment: I have share the code now.Please check